# Setting the quality for ffmpeg command?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, webm

What do I have to add to this command:

cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 10 -vcodec mjpeg -i - out7.webm

to get the best available quality?

Comment: See [FFmpeg Wiki: vpx (WebM) Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the switch "-qscale x".

The lower your x, the better is the quality (range 2 to 32, fractions allowed).
It should work.

Comment: Can you try `-codec:v mjpeg -q:v 2` instead of `-vcodec mjpeg`